# Uploading data from SAS to SQL Server table and � showing up in some values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sas

I'm trying to connect from SAS to SQL Server and insert data into a table. Some columns may contain some accents in unicode. I have been using libname to connect to the server and using proc SQLl to insert into SQL Server.

I have manually created the table on SQL Server such that most of the columns are in `nvarchar format`. However, I noticed after uploading data from SAS to SQL Server, some values show up as �.

Question: I was wondering why some of the values show up as � and how I could resolve this.

Note: encoding in SAS is `utf-8`, whereas encoding in SQL Server is `latin1`

Note2: If I were to export the data in SAS to a csv and then manually upload it to SQL Server, the issue seems to dissappear. But I am trying to find an automation way where I could directly upload from SAS to SQL Server

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your columns to `varchar` vs `nvarchar` since you have control.

Here is a connection string for SQL Server in SAS using ODBC:

```
libname AUDIT ODBC NOPROMPT='server=AUDITD;driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;uid=XXXXX;pwd=YYYYYY;Database=AuditD;' STRINGDATES=NO IGNORE_READ_ONLY_COLUMNS=YES SCHEMA=DBO client_encoding='Latin1';
```

Comment: Is there anyway where I could cast() all the columns so that I could force the columns to nvarchar and then insert into the table (in mssql)?

Comment: Look at my libname allocation, at the end, where I set the encoding to latin1. Unless you need international character support, varchar is more efficient for storage. I am not completely sure what you are asking on the cast. Set the encoding so SAS knows how to do the ODBC translation.